# Multiple directives are not working in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have two directives one to avoid cut, copy and paste and the other to set the limit for the number of characters.  When I use these directives individually i am not getting any errors but when i tried to use both of them in a single html input box i am getting this error:

> [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [limitChar (module: main), stopccp (module: main)] asking for new/isolated scope on:

Cut-copy directive:

```
angular.module('main')
.directive('stopccp', function (){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        link:function (scope, element) {
            element.on('cut copy paste', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Text length directive:

```
angular.module('main')
.directive('limitChar', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            limit: '=limit',
            ngModel: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.$watch('ngModel', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    var length = newValue.toString().length;
                    if (length > scope.limit) {
                        scope.ngModel = oldValue;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Html:

```
<input type="text" stopccp placeholder="{{'notes_message' | translate}}" 
       ng-model="vm.advance.description" id="field2" ng-change="vm.fillStarted()"
       limit-char limit="15">
```

Initially there was no restrict for the stopccp directive.  After that I have restricted to E and I didn't get any errors but i was able to cut, copy and paste. So can anyone tell me what to do.

Comment: And how are you doing DI, where you add the directives to a specific view.

Comment: @TGarrett I am using the directives to the above mentioned html input

Comment: As error clearly stated that, you're applied two directives on same element which are asking for isolated scope, which isn't applicable in angularjs

Comment: @PankajParkar but how could i do that

Comment: @Nidhinkumar I don't think so technically `stopccp` directive needs isolated scope, just remove `scope: {}` line will solve your problem..

Comment: @PankajParkar i have to remove the scope from stopccp directive

Comment: why don't you use the maxlength HTML attribute for the input field instead?